# How can you switch between windows in a stage manager group?

Tags: macos, window-manager, stage-manager

I want to organize my open windows into Stage Manager groups based on my tasks. So, for instance, in one group I might have a browser window and a dev tools window, in a second group I might have a browser and two terminals, and in a third group I might just have a browser.

I need a keyboard shortcut to cycle between *only* the windows in the visible stage manager group. So, that might be two browser windows and a terminal. I *never* want this shortcut to pull up another browser window in a separate group, or to skip any visible window. Surely there must be some way to do this?

Comment: I don’t know if there is a way to do what you want so in case it can’t, have you heard of Hyperfocused? http://hyperfocus.app

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Allan I'm using Chrome, although I don't think that matters.

Comment: Can you create a second profile in Chrome, then launch it with that profile?  It’s best to do this via command line.  This way you have two different instances of Chrome, one in Stage Manager and the other not

Answer (score 0):

I use `` cmd + ` `` but don't remember if that was the default.

[image]